# Как правильно уничтожить сессию?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Пишу обработчик для нажатия по ссылке "Выйти"

```
 <?
 unset($_SESSION[name]);   
 session_destroy();   
 header('Location: index.php');     
 ?>
```

Ругается

> `Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Trying to destroy uninitialized session in Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php on line 3`
>
> `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php:1) in Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php on line 4`

Почему так?

Comment: @Анна, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 6):

На момент выполнения `session_destroy` у вас сессия не активна и соответственно генерируется WARNING. Перед вызовом `session_destroy` необходимо добавить вызов `session_start`.

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['name']); // или $_SESSION = array() для очистки всех данных сессии
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php');
```

Если у вас после `session_destroy` сразу идет редирект то удалять данные из глобальной переменной $_SESSION не обязательно, данные в ней будут доступны только на текущем запросе.

Comment: сделала так, как вы..получилось вот что
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php:1) in Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php on line 2

Comment: Только не забываем `exit;` после `header: location` :) Иначе пойдет дальнейшее выполнение скрипта и редирект произойдет после полной отработки. При удалении `$_SESSION['name']` еще и ошибки будут.

Comment: так как же построить обработчик закрытия сессии..??

Comment: У вас перед вызовом session_start есть вывод (Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php, строка 1).

Comment: session_start() в начале скриптов находится..
о каком выводе вы говорите?

Comment: возможно файл Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php с BOM http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark.

Comment: да нет вроде, пишу в редакторе Scite

Answer (score 3):

Хедер срабатывает потому что скрипт уже отдал тексты ошибок. Хедеры действуют только до отдачи какого-либо текста клиенту, поэтому после выброса ошибок хэдеры не отправляются (это ваше второе предупреждение). А по первому - просто используйте сначала `session_destroy()`, а потом как угодно сбивайте `$_SESSION` :)

Comment: то есть
session_destroy();
 unset($_SESSION[name]);    
 header('Location: index.php');   
 просто местами поменять? но тоже самое получилось(

Answer (score 2):

[удаление сессии](http://php.su/functions/?session-destroy)   и по всей видимости у вас перед

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

имеется  какой-то вывод пользователю. echo ?

Comment: session_start();  запускается при авторизации пользователя, 
на index.php  возвращаемся на главую стрнацу..

только я так и не поняла в чем ошибка..

Comment: session_start(); вызывается не только при авторизации пользователя. она должна вызываться чуть ли не самой первой при каждой загрузке страницы для всех пользователей как авторизованных так и нет. и видимо вам будет много проще сделать loguot на аяксах:  
<script>  
function logout(){  
$.ajax({url:'/logout.php'});  
}  
</script>  
<a href='#' onClick='logout();return false;'>выйти</а>  
или без аякса вовсе:  
<a href='/logout.php'>выйти</а>    
а в loguot.php:  
session_start();  
session_destroy();  
$_SESSION=array();  
// unset($_SESSION[key]); etc..  
header('location: /index.php');